# GNU Assembler adds uncessary padding to the end of the section

Tags: assembly, arm

Consider the following assembler code snipper for the GNU assembler:

```
.section .text
.align 4
.string "text"
```

Without any padding, that would result in a section of 5 bytes with an alignment of 2^4 = 16. However, I verified that the GNU assembler (ARM target) adds padding to the end of the section such that section's length is a multiple of 16. That seems unnecessary as the alignment guarantee is about the beginning of the section, not the end. So why would the assembler add padding at the end? Can this be disabled?

Put the above assembler snipper in a file called test.s and run the following:

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc -c -o test.o test.s
arm-none-eabi-objdump -x test.o
```

Observe that the alignment of the text section is 2^4=16 as requested and that the size of the .text section is 0x10 instead of 5.

Comment: It has something to do with the ARM target. The normal assembler (running `gcc` and `objdump`) shows a `text` section of length 5.

Comment: By normal you mean an Intel target?

Comment: I've just checked clang/llvm 3.6.0 and the integrated assembler creates a .text section of size 5. This wouldn't be the first ARM-related bug in llvm, if it is a bug (I don't think so though).

Comment: Yes, sorry, I meant the Intel target.

Comment: Most sections relate to different access properties anyway - so on most platform syou end up unpacking to 4K pages as that is the MMU or MPU granule size.I'd suggest not worrying about it  ...

Comment: I assume that you refer to loading an ELF image into RAM. But with the padding, the linker can't even pack the sections from the different *.o files that tightly. The linker has no choice but to copy the padding done by the assembler.